# MySql: unchangeable timezone

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

my hosting provider is Godaddy My server location is in Europe and It is in the Amsterdam time zone. support team says :

> "As this is a s\hared hosting platform you would be able to get the
>   time zone which is installed in parent server.you cannot change it" .

i want to show Australian timezone. `php.ini` is not provided. both mysql `Timestamp` and `PHP` function date() showing wrong time.

Comment: Have you even tried to do some researchs? I just googled for it, first 6 links are all providing perfect answers.

Comment: they all say modify php.ini.which is not working in my case

Comment: Then you should may learn to google. `PHP change timezone` - nothing more. First 6 links are all perfect solutions, none of them is saying that you've to modify your php.ini

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

```
ini_set('date.timezone', 'Australia/Australian');
```

I'm not sure about: **Australia/Australian**
You can update it :)

MySQL:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time-zone-support.html